# creating diploma using nested lists ( Python )

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

my collage professor asked to make a diploma that have 2 lists [coruses and students] and nest in it 5 groups in Each group 5 students and fill their names in it Each student have 5 infos(any) all using nested lists.. but later on said do it with anything you could do it with.

i tried to do it in lists and reached this if i appended any input the hole programming goes full of errors

is it possiable in the first place ?

```
diploma = []
std = []
less_than_15 = []
for i in range(5):
    std.append(list(str(i)))
    std[i].remove(str(i))
    std[i].append(list(str(i)))
    std[i][0].remove(str(i))
    std[i][0].append(list(str(i)))
    std[i][0][0].remove(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work the way you expect it to work because of the following reasons:

> You are creating a list of strings instead of a list of lists for each
> student and group. You are removing and appending elements to the
> lists in a confusing and unnecessary way. You are not filling the
> names and infos of the students as required by the problem statement

I'll write a code for you.

for what I figured out.

```
courses = [] 
students = (5,5,5) # it has 5 rows, each with 5 sub-rows, each with 5 elements
```

example:

you can fill it like this:

```
student = [
        #first group
    [
        ["student1", 14, "male", "B-", "math"],
        [                                    ],
                [                                    ],
                [                                    ],
                [                                    ]
        ],

        #second group
        and so on
         

      ]
```

here is all the code you need

```
for i in range(len(students)):
    print(f"Group {i+1}:")
    for j in range(len(students[i])):
        print(f"Student {j+1}: {', '.join(str(x) for x in students[i][j])}")
```

another way to implement the same code is to use random python library:

here is the code

```
import random

# Define the courses list
courses = ["Math", "Science", "English", "History", "Art"]

# Define some sample names and infos
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie","Paul", "Quinn"]
infos = ["Age: 18", "Gender: Female", "Grade: A+", "Course: Math", "Hobby: Painting"]

# Create an empty list for students
students = []

# Loop over 5 groups
for i in range(5):
    # Create an empty list for each group
    group = []
    # Loop over 5 students in each group
    for j in range(5):
        # Create an empty list for each student
        student = []
        # Append a random name to the student list
        student.append(random.choice(names))
        # Loop over 4 infos for each student
        for k in range(4):
            # Append a random info to the student list
            student.append(random.choice(infos))
        # Append the student list to the group list
        group.append(student)
    # Append the group list to the students list
    students.append(group)

# Print the diploma
print("Diploma")
print("Courses: ", ", ".join(courses))
print("Students:")
for i in range(len(students)):
    print(f"Group {i+1}:")
    for j in range(len(students[i])):
        print(f"Student {j+1}: {', '.join(str(x) for x in students[i][j])}")
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to read it and understands it well..